# Anonymous user session in FastAPI and React

Tags: python, reactjs, next.js, cookies, fastapi

I am working on a project in which the backend and frontend are developed by FastAPI and React, respectively.
I want to provide an anonymous user session establishment when a user visits the site and provide that session ID in every API call. I need the session to update user’s request based on their previous requests.

I tried to use cookie ID to distinguish among users but whenever I make the withCredential true on the API request, it returns an error (bad request). I would like to know what is the best practice to handle the session.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I believe you can leverage the authentication and session system provided by FastAPI:

https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/

This system works with usernames and passwords, but you could modify it so that it simply generates 'anonymous_[identifier]' users that don’t require password validation or validation of existence in the database.

**So, you would have two cases:**

1. **User who has never interacted with your API, the 'registration' process:**

You would call the login_for_access_token function, where instead of requesting a username and password, you could generate a username yourself to identify that anonymous user.(for ex 'anonymous_3')

This function would call create_access_token, which would create a session token based on the name you've generated to identify the anonymous user. For example (anonymous_[number]).

2. **User who has already 'registered' and is making requests to your API:**

   In all endpoints, you should pass get_current_user as a dependency. This function would decode the token and check if it contains 'anonymous[identifier]' in the username. If so, on each request you could read the get_current_user and know which anonymous user is interacting with that endpoint, achieving your goal.

You could store those anonymous users in the database. This way, when they interact with certain endpoints, you can store their actions in that database. Consequently, when they make a new request, you can identify the users through the token, look up their previous actions in the database, and act based on its previous requests.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I appreciate it. I was able to find an alternative solution to my problem that required minimal effort. I opted to use UUID instead of dealing with token exchange. However, I will keep in mind your recommendation for future reference when I need to scale up my project.

Comment: How did you implement your UUID solution? Curious to hear details, were you just setting and reading a session id cookie that was a UUID?